# Please help me check this derivative work - logistic regression algorithm related

Tags: derivatives

I have

$$
J_{\theta}(X) = - \frac 1 m \cdot \left[ y \cdot ln( h_{\theta} (X ) ) + ( 1 - y) \cdot ln ( 1 - h_{\theta}(X) ) \right]
$$

I need $\frac d {d\theta} J_{\theta}(X)$. I tried many time, and here's my result

$$
\frac d {d\theta} J_{\theta}(X) = - \frac 1 m \cdot
\left[
\frac y {h_{\theta}(X)} -
\frac { (1 - y) } { 1 - h_{\theta}(X)}
\right]
\cdot \frac d {d\theta} h_{\theta}(X)
$$

But when I plug in the result of $\frac d {d\theta}h_{\theta}(X)$, I cannot get the expected result, which is

$$
\frac 1 m \cdot (h_{\theta}(X) - y) \cdot X 
$$

$h_{\theta}(X)$ and its derivative are defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860750/help-me-check-my-homework).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to arrive at the maximum likelihood equations for a logistic regression model, where $h_\theta(X)$ is the parametrization of the probabilities of binomial random variables $Y$'s w.r.t. data $X$'s and parameters $\theta$.

I suggest to have a look at the first answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477207/derivative-of-cost-function-for-logistic-regression/477261#477261) and its calculations. Some care has to be taken w.r.t. the indices "hidden" in your equation; they play an important role. Remember, for example, that the $i$-th observation $y_i$ of the binomial r.v. $Y_i$ depends only on the $i$-th observation $x_i$ of the whole dataset $X$ (consequently, the probability for $Y_i$ is parametrized as $h_i:=h(x_i,\theta)$.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It looks like that guy is doing the same thing as I am doing :)

Comment: Very good! Please, check my answer in the link if you need computations with indices (I am lazy and I did not want to write it twice, sorry)